# Java JTextArea overlaps JMenuItem

Tags: java, swing, awt, mixing, jmenubar

I have a jmenu called file with one menu item called quit when you click it it activates

> System.exit(0);

its all fine until in the jtextfield when ever I enter anything and click enter If I then click on the file button on the jmenubar the quit button is hidden under the jtextarea.

Its quite hard to explain so here is a before and after typing image:
 [image]

Iv'e looked into it and It could be something to do with focusing but any attempts to refocusing the quit button haven't worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- looks like as issue with `awt.ScrollPane`, have to use `swing.JScrollPane` instead
- you are issue [with mixing lightweight](https://blogs.oracle.com/thejavatutorials/entry/mixing_heavyweight_and_lightweight_components) and [heavyweight components](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/mixing-components-433992.html)